# why :first-child selector not working in this case?

Tags: html, css

See example http://jsfiddle.net/qqyYU/1/

```
<div class="detail">

    <p><b>Entry</b><br>

First <span>40,-</span><br>

Second <span>20,-</span></p></div>
```

css

```
.detail p span:first-child {background:yellow;}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first-child of your `<p>` is a `<b>` tag, not a `<span>`:

"This pseudo-class matches an element **only if it’s the first child element** of its parent element." (http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-firstchild)

**EDIT**
You may be able to use the adjacent sibling selector if you can't change the class of the element and you are required to support IE7 (though it may not work):

http://jsfiddle.net/qqyYU/5/

Comment: +1 oh. then how to only select first span without adding class to it

Comment: @JitendraVyas You may be able to use the adjacent sibling selector.

Answer (score 2):

What you want for your CSS is:

```
.detail p span:nth-of-type(1) {background:yellow;}
```

Unfortunately this has poor browser support.

Comment: Not going to get it with just CSS, then. jQuery and friends will be your only option, or adding a class to your `<span>`.